# Solve the right triangle ABC knowing that $a = 5$ and $r = 1$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[ABC Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpijo.png)

The question in my textbook isn't very clear and there are no pictures but I believe $r$ is the inscribed circumference radius as the picture I made.

I need to calculate all triangle sides and angles.

Let's also assume that $Â$ is the right angle and the opposite side is $a$

Comment: Try to write down Pythagorean theorem and formula of area of triangle using the radius, something should come out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I think u can calculate angles 37 and 53

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for an inscribed circle, with radius $\text{R}$, in a right angled triangle $\triangle\text{ABC}$, with sides $\text{a}$, $\text{b}$, and $\text{c}$ (where $\text{c}$ is the hypotenuse), we know that:

$$\text{R}=\frac{\text{a}+\text{b}-\text{c}}{2}\tag1$$

For a proof look [here](https://mathschallenge.net/full/inscribed_circle_in_right_angled_triangle).

Comment: Why the downvote?